# Java Database ELSE IF not working

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to allow users who input the correct credentials, however, my else-if statement does not work. I would greatly, and I mean greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

SORRY THE STUFF IN THE ELSE-IF STATEMENT DOES NOT HAPPEN! SO IF I INPUT THE WRONG CREDENTIALS, NOTHING HAPPENS.

My code:

```
while(db.next()){
  if (first.equals(db.getString("name") && last.equals(db.getString("last")){
    try{
      con.autocommit(false);
      String sql = "UPDATE details SET name = ('"+givenName+"') WHERE SET name = ('"+givenName+"')
      PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      st.executeUpdate();
      con.commit();
      con.setAutoCommit(true)
  else if (!first.equals(db.getString("name") && !last.equals(db.getString("last")){
      System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
}
```

Once again, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out and explain why my else if not working.

Comment: "It does not work" is probably the worst possible description of an error...  Can you describe a bit better what happens and why that's not what you expect.

Comment: @fvu Sorry, the statement in the else-if block doesn't take placement. It doesn't print "incorrect username or password" if I actually input the wrong details

Comment: This looks like it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Your else if clause probably wants || instead of && (De Morgan's law)

Comment: Although, that would make it just "else".

Comment: This does not compile. Where's the `catch` (pun not intended)? Paste your full code, please

Comment: Shouldn't you have } before the else (there is one after the if) also there should be a ; after con.setAutoCommit(true)

Comment: Also you should end the try{

Answer (score 1):

The if-statement code appears to have a contradiction of intent. (I'm purposefully ignoring numerous other issues, including syntax that won't compile and what appears to be a missing "password check".)

```
if (first.equals(db.getString("name") && last.equals(db.getString("last"))
  // ..
else if (!first.equals(db.getString("name") && !last.equals(db.getString("last"))
  // ..
```

Using substitutes and rewriting the expressions yields

```
if (A && B)
  // ..
else if (!A && !B)
  // ..
```

*Assuming* that the goal is to always run *either* the code in the `if` *or* the `else if`, then this poses a problem; the transformation of `!(A && B)` is `!A || !B`, by [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), and *not* `!A && !B` as written in the code.

If such is the case, while it *could* be rewritten as `if (A && B) .. else if (!(A && B)) ..`, I would suggest simply using an `else` to avoid this "problem" to begin with:

```
if (A && B)
   // "valid" first/last names, but where is the password check?
else
   // otherwise, "invalid" first/last names
```

Comment: It's not a logical contradiction. if (A || B) should put you into the else clause.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst Contradiction "of intent", I'll clarify. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I up voted you because the answer is correct but throwing in De Morgan's Law obviates the answer a bit.  Though the statement is correct, I don't think it has anything to do with this situation.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst Thanks for the continued feedback. While I'm fond of leaving the in DM transformation, it is a valid point of not necessarily being directly relevant. I've expanded that area of the answer directly to illustrate how/why this might matter.

Comment: Yes, okay, you tied it in nicely.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, there are some syntax errors in your code. I do not really know if that is a trimmed version or the complete code.

Check for the unclosed if's (and their unclosed parentheses), also the try is missing the catch block. There are also semicolons missing in two lines, one which also has an unclosed string literal.

Now, more into the logic itself, this (i'm quoting):

```
else if (!first.equals(db.getString("name") && !last.equals(db.getString("last")){
  System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
```

is not appropriate, because unless you remove the **if** part and leave it just like a simple **else**, you are really stating "Incorrect username AND password"